# Write RTF to clipboard and paste into Word

Tags: r, rtf

I am using the [rtf](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rtf/) package to export R data frames to Microsoft Word. However, what I would really like to do is to be able to write the underlying RTF to the clipboard and then paste the table directly into Word. I've tried pasting raw RTF as follows,

```
write(RTF_TEXT, "clipboard")
```

but when I paste into Word I just get the raw ASCII text contained in `RTF_TEXT`, not the formatted object represented by it. Assuming I am able to generate a properly formatted table in RTF, is there a way to copy it to the clipboard so that I can paste it straight into Word?

Comment: I use the DescTools package and its excellent set of functions to add plots and tables to Word.  For example, wrdPlot and wrdTable.  Perhaps they will help.  There is also the ReporteRs package and its capabilities to export tables, text and plots to Word.

Comment: I'm with the same problem, but from `highlight` command output to highlight a c source. Just want to grab the RTF and paste to openoffice writer. Sounds trick.